# Cannot select columns from Database with Android Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to simply grab every single row currently in my SQLite database on my Android and grab each individual column from each row. I believe the data is actually in the database, because I call a separate function DataHelper.selectAll() to print out to Log all of the data. The data I expect correctly shows up in LogCat in Eclipse. If it's important, the DataHelper.java program I'm basically using is found here: http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742. I'll post relevant code below. The important stuff is in doPost().

```
    // from inside onCreate of Main (which extends activity)...
    Button buttonPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPost);
    buttonPost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     // doesn't actually post to website yet
     public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d(TAG, "In onclicklistener.");
         ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

         if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Connected, calling doPost()!");
          if (doPost()) {
                      // ...
                }
            }
     }
    }); 

public boolean doPost() {
   boolean outcome = false;
   long ret = dh.insert(main.id++ + "," + "my test2" + "," + "5:4:2:3" + "," + -300 + "," + -300 + "," + -1 + "," +
-70 + "," + 3 + "," + -3 + "," + main.device_id);
   Log.d(TAG, "ret from static insert:" + ret);

   Cursor cursor = this.dh.db.query(DataHelper.TABLE_NAME, 
      new String[] { "id", "rssi", "wap_id", "lat" },
      null, null, null, null, "id desc");
   Log.d(TAG, "Cursor column count: " + cursor.getColumnCount());
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do { 
       HttpPost post = new HttpPost(OUR_SERVER);
       Log.d(TAG, "rssi index:" + cursor.getColumnIndex("rssi"));
       Log.d(TAG, "the rssi: " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("rssi")));
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }

   // release connection here?
   cm.shutdown();

   if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
      cursor.close();
   }
 return outcome;
}
```

Now what's strange about this is in my LogCat it successfully printed out the full rows (just as a string), so I know I'm able to access the database. The rssi values that I expect are not logged, instead I get:

```
Cursor column count: 4
id value: 6
id index: 0
rssi index:1
the rssi: 0
id value: 5
id index: 0
rssi index:1
the rssi: 0
```

I'm at a loss, because plenty of online examples all access data the same way. Does it have to do with the fact that I'm within an OnClickListener? There are no debugger warnings when I do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Turns out that DataHelper.java class I was using just inserts everything into the first column. This was pretty counter-intuitive. That's what I get for finding code online and assuming it does the right thing.

To fix this, I manually wrote a full SQL statement, compiled the statement, and ran it.